# Way to loop over Counter by number of times present?

Tags: python

I am using collections.Counter and I am trying to loop over the elements. However if I have `t=Counter("AbaCaBA")` and use a for loop to print each element, it would only print one of each letter:

```
   for i in t:
       print(i)
```

would print:

```
    a
    C
    A
    b
    B
```

How would I loop over it in  a way that would print as many of each letter as there are? As in, 2 A's, 2 a's, 1 b, 1 B, 1 C.

Edit: apparently there is a method called elements() that serves this exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a `Counter` you are iterating over the keys. In order to get the counts at the same time you could do something like:

```
for i, count in t.items():
    print('{} {}s'.format(count, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the elements() method shortly after posting this, here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

It returns an iterator that repeats each element as many times as it is counted, ignoring elements with counts<1

```
    for i in t.elements():
         print(i)
```